# Qt Signals and slots

Tags: qt

How many signals at maximum you can connect to a single slot? If more than one how you can do that? How many slots can you connect to a signal? If more than one how those slots will be executed? How a Qt Program/Application written for one platform (Symbian) can be ported/executed in another

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 5):

You can easily connect more than one slot to a single signal using the usual way (`QObject::connect`), which are then called in order of connection when the signal is emitted.

Likewise can a single slot be connected to multiple signals, which is then called whenever one of those signals is emitted. You can even chain signals by connecting signals to signals, which are then emitted automatically whenever the source signal is emitted.

Such information can easily be gained by [Qt's excellent documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html).

There may be a theoretical limit on the number of slots that can be connected to a signal, but this limit is surely beyond any practical relevance.

Although porting an application from an embedded system, like Symbian, to a desktop system, like Windows, may involve some additional issues, in general the porting of a Qt application to another platform just requires recompilation on/for that platform, assuming you didn't use any platform-dependent code in the rest of your application, which is usually not neccessary when using Qt.

Comment: It make sense to mention QSignalMapper class which makes possible to maps signals from group of objects to single slot and pass parameter to identify which object was sending signal.

Answer (score 1):

you can connect as many slots to a signal as you wish. They will be executed in order in which they were connected.

Generally if you use only qt and no other platform dependent API, then recompiling it on target platform should be enough. Have no idea about Symbian though - sometimes Symbian seems to have a bit different rules.

Comment: Qt is designed to be "platform-independent", that is, you can write the code once and run it wherever Qt libraries exist(recompile needed anyway)

Comment: I don't mean that it will not work compiled on different platform, but when it comes to GUI, symbian seems to know better here and there (it's mobile os - it have to), so depending on what you actually have done, there might be some little quirks - nothing I worry about though.